# jQuery Contact Form with PHP fallback

Tags: php, validation, mootools, contact-form

I have followed THIS tutorial on how to make a Contact Form using PHP and jQuery.
For what i understand the idea is to have the jquery working and the php as a "backup".

I followed the tutorial without any problems. Or so i thought...
But in the end it seems the jQuery is not working. I always get a "blink" (a page refresh) when validating.

This is the page i was trying to use it in:
http://dccf.site88.net/test/dccf.php

here is the PHP:

```
// Set email variables
$email_to = 'luis_bento@hotmail.com';
$email_subject = 'Message from DCCF site';

// Set required fields
$required_fields = array('fullname','email','comment');

// set error messages
$error_messages = array(
    'fullname' => 'Please enter a Name to proceed.',
    'email' => 'Please enter a valid Email.',
    'comment' => 'Please enter a Message to continue.'
);

// Set form status
$form_complete = FALSE;

// configure validation array
$validation = array();

// check form submittal
if(!empty($_POST)) {
    // Sanitise POST array
    foreach($_POST as $key => $value) $_POST[$key] = remove_email_injection(trim($value));

    // Loop into required fields and make sure they match our needs
    foreach($required_fields as $field) {       

        // the field has been submitted?
        if(!array_key_exists($field, $_POST)) array_push($validation, $field);

        // check there is information in the field?
        if($_POST[$field] == '') array_push($validation, $field);

        // validate the email address supplied
        if($field == 'email') if(!validate_email_address($_POST[$field])) array_push($validation, $field);
    }

    // basic validation result
    if(count($validation) == 0) {

        // Prepare our content string
        $email_content = 'New Website Comment: ' . "\n\n";

        // simple email content
        foreach($_POST as $key => $value) {
            if($key != 'submit') $email_content .= $key . ': ' . $value . "\n";
        }

        // if validation passed ok then send the email
        mail($email_to, $email_subject, $email_content);

        // Update form switch
        $form_complete = TRUE;
    }
}
function validate_email_address($email = FALSE) {
    return (preg_match('/^[^@\s]+@([-a-z0-9]+\.)+[a-z]{2,}$/i', $email))? TRUE : FALSE;
}
function remove_email_injection($field = FALSE) {
   return (str_ireplace(array("\r", "\n", "%0a", "%0d", "Content-Type:", "bcc:","to:","cc:"), '', $field));
}
?>




        <div id="formWrap">
    <h2>If you like our project, have any questions, or would like more information, please send us a message.</h2><!-- end of "Form Message" h2 -->
    <div id="form">
    <?php if($form_complete === FALSE): ?>
    <form action="dccf.php" method="post" id="comments_form">
        <div  class="row">
            <div class="label">Your Name:</div><!-- end of .label -->
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="fullname" class="detail" name="fullname" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['fullname'])? $_POST['fullname'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('fullname', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- end of .input -->
            <div class="context">e.g. John Smith or Jane Doe</div><!-- end of .context --> 
        </div><!-- end of .row -->

        <div  class="row">
            <div class="label">Your Email:</div><!-- end of .label -->
            <div class="input">
                <input type="text" id="email" class="detail" name="email" value="<?php echo isset($_POST['email'])? $_POST['email'] : ''; ?>" /><?php if(in_array('email', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- end of .input -->
            <div class="context">e.g. youremail@somewhere.com</div><!-- end of .context --> 
        </div><!-- end of .row -->

        <div  class="row">
            <div class="label">Your Message:</div><!-- end of .label -->
            <div class="input">
                <textarea id="comment" name="comment" class="mess"><?php echo isset($_POST['comment'])? $_POST['comment'] : ''; ?></textarea><?php if(in_array('comment', $validation)): ?><span class="error"><?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?></span><?php endif; ?>
            </div><!-- end of .input -->
        </div><!-- end of .row -->

        <div class="submit">
            <input type="submit" id="submit" name="submit" value"Send Message" />
        </div><!-- end of .submit -->

        </form>
        <?php else: ?>
        <p class="thanks">Thank you for your Message! We will get back to you as soon as possible.</p>
        <?php endif; ?>
    </div><!-- end of #form -->
</div><!-- end of #formWrap -->
```

and the java script:
on the :

```
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var nameError = '<?php echo $error_messages['fullname']; ?>';
    var emailError = '<?php echo $error_messages['email']; ?>';
    var commentError = '<?php echo $error_messages['comment']; ?>';
</script>
```

in the validation.js:

```
    window.addEvent('domready', function() {
// Get the form
var form = $('comments_form');

//  if the form is found...
if (form) {
    // obtain error fields
    var name = $('fullname');
    var email = $('email');
    var comment = $('comment');

    // Set the default status
    var isValid = true;

    // input error function for the error messages
    var addError = function (field, msg) {
        field.addClass('error'); // Add error class to field
        var error = field.getParent().getElement('span') || new Element('span', {'class': 'error'}); // add error message if not already placed
        error.set('text', msg); // error text msg
        error.inject(field, 'after'); // Insert error message after field
    };

    // detach error function used to delete any error messages and remove the error class
    var removeError = function (field) {
        field.removeClass('error'); // Remove error class from form fields
        var error = field.getParent().getElement('span'); // find any existing error messages

        // destroy if error message
        if (error) {
            error.destroy();
        }
    };

    //  insert submit form event
    form.addEvent('submit', function (e) {
        // Test name length
        if (name.get('value').length === 0) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(name, nameError);
        } else {
            isValid = true;
            removeError(name);
        }

        // check email length
        if (email.get('value').length === 0) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(email, emailError);
        // check email validity
        } else if (!email.get('value').test(/^([a-zA-Z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/)) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(email, emailError);
        } else {
            isValid = true;
            removeError(email);
        }

        // check comment length
        if (comment.get('value').length === 0) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(comment, commentError);
        } else {
            isValid = true;                     
            removeError(comment);
        }

        // If form invalid then stop event happening
        if (!isValid) {
            e.stop();
        }
    });
}   
});
```

Thank you for your help!
=)

Edit:
got a couple of **errors** on the console (on loading the page, not one submiting the form):

- Viewport argument key "width_device-width" not recognized and ignored.    dccf.php:8
- TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'form.addEvent')     validation.js:4

Comment: yes. i dind't know there was a console!   Sorry.

So, the errors are:
Typeerror: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating'form.addEvent')   validation.js:4

there are a cuple other errors, but this is the one i think related to this topic

Comment: Hit F12 in IE and Chrome and FX if [firebug](http://getfirebug.com/) is installed

Comment: @ mplungjan
the errors are:

Viewport argument key "width_device-width" not recognized and ignored.   dccf.php:8

TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'form.addEvent')    validation.js:4

any idea what this means?

Comment: It means you are asking in the wrong area. It is mootools not jQuery. I will change you tags

Answer (score 0):

I have removed my previous answer since there were MANY issues with your code.

Here is the jQuery equivalent with all errors removed so it

1. no longer allows submission if just one of the later fields were filled in
2. is not using string.test(regex) but instead the correct regex.test(string)
3. is using fullname instead of name for the name field
4. resets isValid each time submit is pressed

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/mplungjan/mjCxd/)

```
$(function() {
  // Get the form
  var form = $('#comments_form');

  //  if the form is found...
  if (form) {

    // input error function for the error messages
    var addError = function (field, msg) {
        field.addClass('error'); // Add error class to field
        var error = field.parent().find('span') || $('<span>', {'class': 'error'}); // add error message if not already placed
        error.html(msg); // error text msg
        field.after(error); // Insert error message after field
    };

    // detach error function used to delete any error messages and remove the error class
    var removeError = function (field) {
        field.removeClass('error'); // Remove error class from form fields
        var error = field.parent().find('span'); // find any existing error messages

        // destroy if error message
        if (error) {
            error.remove();
        }
    };

    //  insert submit form event
    form.on('submit', function (e) {


        // Set the default status
        var isValid = true;

        // Test name length
        var name = $("#fullname");
        if (name.val().length === 0) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(name, nameError);
        } else {
            removeError(name);
        }

        // check email length
        var email = $("#email");
        var emailVal = email.val();
        if (emailVal.length === 0) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(email, emailError);
        // check email validity
        } else if (!/^([a-zA-Z0-9\+_\-]+)(\.[a-zA-Z0-9\+_\-]+)*@([a-zA-Z0-9\-]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,6}$/.test(emailVal)) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(email, emailError);
        } else {
            removeError(email);
        }

        // check comment length
        var comment = $("#comment");
        console.log(comment.val())
        if (comment.val().length === 0) {
            isValid = false;
            addError(comment, commentError);
        } else {
            removeError(comment);
        }

        // If form invalid then stop event happening
        if (!isValid) {
            e.preventDefault();
        }
    });
  }   
});
```

Comment: what could i do? use a more recent version of mootools?

Comment: I have just tried with the most recent version of Mootools and i get the same result...  =(

Comment: your Fiddle works just fine. i am very BEGINNER and i really can't find what is the problem. Would it help if i post the FULL code (the full code in the dccf.pfp file)? I am using another jquery script for a photo slider, can it be that some how they "interfere" with one another?

Comment: yes, in your Fiddle it is fine. Please tell me, what do i have to do? Copy the Java script there on Fiddle into my "validation.js"? What about the PHP, everything is the same? (Thank you for your help! i'm really lost with this...)

Comment: Take the code I posted above and use it to replace the file called `/test/contact/validation/validation.js` on your site. Then remove mootools (as seen in lines 17, 18 and 19 in this page: `view-source:http://dccf.site88.net/test/dccf.php`) - then you are done

Comment: ok. i have replaced to validation.js with the code you provided and i have taken out the links to the mootools.
But now when i click the SEND button nothing happens. it doesn't send any message nor gives the error messages...   any ideas?

Comment: Yes, please see update, I had to move the var isValid. Also it seems the error message is not added in your script.

Comment: hi. first of all, thank you for you your help!!!  I have copyed the whole script you have to the validation.js. I uploaded it but i still get nothing when clicking on Submit.
On console the is an error on validation.js:3.
I have made a Fiddle with the full PHP file, some of the css and the validation.js: http://jsfiddle.net/c22DY/1/

Comment: Someone or something wrapped my code in `window.addEvent('domready', function() { .... }` - please remove first and last line in validation.js

Comment: i did... when there is the window.addEvent('domready', function() { .... } then the page blinks and the php validation works. when there is no window.addEvent('domready', function() { .... } then nothing happens. I just wanted to try what happend with that!

Comment: Please remove it and do not add it back. Ten I can test your page with my script

Comment: ok. i uploaded again the version without ONLY your code on the validation.js. also updated the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/c22DY/2/    thank you!

Comment: Works for me (except showing the errors - that is another issue) I get Thank you for your Message! We will get back to you as soon as possible. when I fill in all fields correctly.

Comment: for me it also works, but it is the Server Side (php) validation. That is why we see a "flash/refresh" and why the page goes back to the top.
And the error messages also don't show...   =(

Comment: This is getting more like a job now.

Comment: Yes, you are right, you have been really patient and helpful. Thank you!

Comment: i found out something new. Both your's and the original validation.js work IF there are no other script running (like the picture slider). If they are running then the validation doesn't work any more.